# linux include all directories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, utf-8, terminal

how would I type a file path in ubuntu terminal to include all files in all sub-directories?

If I had a main directory called "books" but had a ton of subdirectories with all sorts of different names containing files, how would I type a path to include all files in all subdirectories?

/books/???

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: in what context? in a scripting language or at the command line as input to a shell command?  some more info would be useful..

Comment: Typically, if a tool supports this, there will be a flag that can be passed to the tool to recurse subdirectories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you actually want ... Probably you will get a better solution to your problem, if you ask directly for it, not for one other problem you've come accross trying to circumvent the original problem.

do you mean something like the following?

```
file */*
```

where the first `*` expands for all subdirectories and the second `*` for all contained files ?

I have chosen the `file` command arbitrarily. You can choose whatever command you want to run on the files you get shell-expanded. 
Also note that directories will also be included (if not excluded by name, e.g. `*.png` or `*.txt`).
The wildcard `*` is not exactly *the file path to include all files in all subdirectories* but it expands to all files (or directories) matching the wildcard expression as a list, e.g. `file1 file2 file3 file4`. See also [this tutorial on shell expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html).

Note that there may be easy solutions to related problems. Like to copy all files in all subdirectories (`cp -a` for example, see `man cp`).

I also like `find` very much. It's quite easy to generate more flexible search patterns in combination with `grep`. To provide a random example:

```
du `find . | grep some_pattern_to_occur | grep -v some_pattern_to_not_occur`
```

Comment: I've never noticed this command before, so thanks for sharing it.  When I try it, it reports directories as well as files, plus it provides more information regarding the type of file/directory it is, such as 
`api:                 directory`
`api/pom.xml:         XML  document text`
So I think to use this to iterate through files you would have to run it through something to remove everything after the file name, and then the command you're running it through would have to be able to handle directories.  I took a quick look through `man file` and didn't see a way to avoid the extra info.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  Thanks for the follow up :)

Answer (score 1):

From within the books top directory, you can use the command:

`find . -type f`

Then, if you wanted to, say run each file through cat, you could use the xargs command:

`find . -type f | xargs cat`

For more info, use commands:

`man find`

`man xargs`

Comment: This is the correct way to traverse a hierarchy of subdirectories. Some shells offer a wildcard syntax `**/*` for this but Bash v2 is not amongst them.

Comment: Any Ubuntu version that is yet supported uses bash version 3 or higher for the terminal (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

```
./books/*
```

For example, assuming i'm in the parent directory of 'books':

```
ls ./books/*
```

**EDIT:**

Actually, to list all the tree recursively you should use:

```
ls -R ./books/*
```